# Auto Categorize Emails using Subfolder Names

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a shared inbox that has several subfolders.

I want to use the subfolder names as the category for each email inside the relevant subfolder instead of creating a category and a rule for each folder.

As an example, I want to auto categorize the emails in "Support" with "Project A - Support" and the emails in "Project A" with "Project A"

- Inbox

  - Project A

    - Support
  - Project B
  - Project C

```vb
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

Private Const AUTO_CATEGORY As String = "(test)"

Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Dim Ns As Outlook.NameSpace
  Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
  Dim Subfolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

  Set Ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

  Set Inbox = Ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

  Set Subfolder = Inbox.Folders

  Set Items = Subfolder.Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
  Dim Cats() As String
  Dim i&
  Dim Exists As Boolean

  If Len(Item.Categories) Then
    Cats = Split(Item.Categories, ";")
    For i = 0 To UBound(Cats)
      If LCase$(Cats(i)) = LCase$(AUTO_CATEGORY) Then
        Exists = True
        Exit For
      End If
    Next

    If Exists = False Then
      Item.Categories = Item.Categories & ";" & AUTO_CATEGORY
      Item.Save
    End If

  Else
    Item.Categories = AUTO_CATEGORY
    Item.Save
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev the codes i know let me categorize the moved or received emails with a specific category that i write in the script.

I don't know if there is a code to do what i need.

Comment: Could you publish the code which you've developed so far so that we could suggest the required changes?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev, I publish the code as you requested.

Answer (score 0):

`ItemAdd` is as tedious as rules. You need code for each folder.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents SubfolderProjectAItems As Items
Private WithEvents SubfolderProjectASupportItems As Items

Private WithEvents SubfolderProjectBItems As Items
Private WithEvents SubfolderProjectCItems As Items


Private Sub Application_Startup()

    Dim myInbox As folder
    
    Dim SubfolderProjectA As folder
    Dim SubfolderProjectASupport As folder
    
    Dim SubfolderProjectB As folder
    Dim SubfolderProjectC As folder
    
    Set Inbox = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    
    Set SubfolderProjectA = Inbox.folders("Project A")
    Set SubProjectAItems = SubfolderProjectA.Items
    
    Set SubfolderProjectASupport = SubfolderProjectA.folders("Support")
    Set SubfolderProjectASupportItems = SubfolderProjectASupport.Items
    
    Set SubfolderProjectB = Inbox.folders("Project B")
    Set SubfolderProjectBItems = SubfolderProjectB.Items
    
    Set SubfolderProjectC = Inbox.folders("Project C")
    Set SubfolderProjectCItems = SubfolderProjectC.Items
  
End Sub


Private Sub testPA()
    SubfolderProjectA_ItemAdd ActiveInspector.currentItem
End Sub


Private Sub SubfolderProjectA_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    
    Dim catStr As String
    
    catStr = Item.Parent
        
    If InStr(Item.categories, catStr) = 0 Then
        Item.categories = Item.categories & ";" & catStr
        Item.Save
    End If

End Sub


Private Sub testPASupport()
    SubfolderProjectASupportItems_ItemAdd ActiveInspector.currentItem
End Sub

Private Sub SubfolderProjectASupportItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

    Dim catStr As String
    
    catStr = Item.Parent.Parent & " - " & Item.Parent
    
    If InStr(Item.categories, catStr) = 0 Then
        Item.categories = Item.categories & ";" & catStr
        Item.Save
    End If
    
End Sub
```